# Question about the ring of polynomials bounded on a real variety

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $I$ is a  prime real radical ideal in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. "Real radical" means that if a sum of squares $a^2+b^2+\ldots$ is an element of $I$ then so are the polynomials $a, b,\ldots$. Let  $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the zero-set of $I$, and assume that $V$ is unbounded.  Obviously the ring $B:=\mathbb{R}[I+\mathbb{R}]$ consists entirely of of polynomials bounded on $V$. Is every polynomial bounded on $V$ necessarily an element of the ring $B$?

Comment: Are you assuming $I$ is prime, radical, etc.? Otherwise, take something like $I = (x_1^2 - x_2^2)$.

Comment: Anomaly, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: [Sketch of a possible proof]. We can use [resolution of singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities). Blow the ideal up until it is monomial, in particular the strict transform is smooth. Consider a polynomial $p$ that is bounded on $V$. Then its transform $p'$ is bounded on the strict transform $V'$ of $V$. Restrict $p'$ to $V'$, you get a bounded regular function. Therefore it is constant $c$. Then $p'-c$ vanishes on $V'$. Since $V'$ is smooth the generator of its ideal divides $p'-c$. Now we transform back.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had thought more about this before I posted. Anyway, here is a counterexample. Let $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be the polynomial $y(x^2+1)-1$. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $f$. Let $V$ be the zero-set of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Writing the equation $f=0$ in the form $$y=\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$ it is clear that the polynomial $y$ is bounded on $V$. Moreover $y$ is not an element of the ring $\mathbb{R}[\mathbb{R}+I]$ because $y$ is not constant as a function on $V$. We must verify that $I$ is prime and real radical.

1. $I$ is prime: To check this, we note that the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/I$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,1/(1+x^2)]$, which is an integral domain, being a subring of the field $\mathbb{R}(x)$.
2. I is real radical: It is enough to find an order on the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,1/(1+x^2)]$. But the field $\mathbb{R}(x)$ can be ordered: For example think of the elements as functions on $\mathbb{R}$ ordered by eventual domination.

It seems that the general problem of calculating the ring of bounded functions on a real variety is much much harder than I realized. If anyone has any references or thoughts on the matter please post.

Comment: Interesting. What is the answer over the complex numbers?

Comment: Pp, Over the complexes, with "real radical" replaced by "radical", I don't see a counter-example. It does  seem that Liouville's theorem and  desingularization might be relevant.